# symfony 2.6 buildForm versus createFormBuilder

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

someone can explain me the difference between buildForm and CreateFormBuilder?
what is the best way to create forms? I'm reading symblog and it uses:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('subject');
        $builder->add('body', 'textarea');
```

but in documentation symfony i find use of "createFormBuilder"

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // createFormBuilder is a shortcut to get the "form factory"
        // and then call "createBuilder()" on it
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('task', 'text')
            ->add('dueDate', 'date')
            ->getForm();
        return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example you've shown is the right way to do it. Why?

- Best practices. A form type should live in its own namespace - *BundleName\Form\Type* for instance. It's a better practice to do it that way, because you're free to re-use the form type anywhere you want in your application. Everything your form needs is placed in one file, easier to understand, not just by you, also by someone who can work on your project in future. That would be the first place every developer should look for, if something needs to be changed/added. Once you start adding event listeners, custom validators and more into your forms, you will understand that a controller is not a suitable place for a form to be defined.
- DRY - every developer is aiming to write better code everyday. One of the most important concepts regarding controllers is - keep it as thin as possible. Let the controller action do only what it's supposed to do, nothing more - nothing less. Once your form types are defined, then its only a matter of few lines to create and render your form.

To answer your first questions - no, there is not much of a difference, whether you create your form in separate class or not. There is a lot more to discuss on this matter, but I believe this would be enough for you to understand the idea behind form type as a class. My suggestion to you, is to keep your forms in their own namespace.

Hope this can clarify things for you.

Comment: thanks !! there is a lot of symfony's documentation  but not detailed explanation like yours. !

Comment: one question: why both ways, dont use: use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;  or is a new way use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;  but in the example of symfony documentation just use: use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Comment: Becasue `$this->createFormBuilder()` is a shortcut that comes from Symfony's Controller that you extend. And as for the second one, the form type extends specific class.

Comment: Something to add in case it's not obvious.Most examples show CRUD type code where the form data_class option points to a Doctrine entity. Don't forget that the data_class can be any plain old PHP object. I find that it keeps things clean if I always create an object behind a form even if the form is something very simple and not connected to an entity. Validation then goes in the object, not "constraints" on the form which is possible but not really the correct place.